# Element overflow has highest z-index in page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page, in which I open a modal, with a canvas element presenting a 2d map.
There is an area in the modal, where the map is displayed, in which it intersects with the overflow of the content behind the modal (the main page).

For some weird reason, when the cursor is over the overflow of the content behind the modal, the cursor (and pointer events) are captured in the content behind the modal.

I checked all my positioning, and content is static, while the dialog is absolute.
No z-index for the overflow.
I thought this is a bug in Chrome, but it also occurs in Brave.

In the below image it is possible to see, that when I got to the point where my cursor intersects with the overflow, I right-clicked, inspect element, and the content behind the modal was selected as it is "hijacking" the pointer event.
The point where my cursor is, at the right side where the padding & margin boundaries are displayed.

I searched but found nothing about this issue.
Currently when the modal is displayed I do "pointer-events: none" for the content behind and the issue is resolved.
Yet I would prefer to understand what is going on and solve it properly :(

Any advice/documentation on this issue would be highly appreciated!
[image: Element is select though, modal is on top of everything]

Comment: Do you have a link to share so that we can investigate the problem from our side?

Comment: You can possibly try and increase the z-index for the map canvas and try to see. if this is still an issue

Comment: Sorry LakshyaRaj, it is a password protected application and I can't share it.
innocent I tried 99999, yet the same behavior.

If you have any more inspection data to help you analyze that I'll be happy to share.

Comment: Inspect on which element is the overflow. When you open the open, you put it hidden, and back when modal close.